# How can I turn this jquery into a function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to turn the below jquery code into a function so i could add links to the list and not have to touch the jquery. I'm assuming I will have to put the image name into the `<a href>` tag somewhere.

html code

```
<img id="storyimg" src="1.png" alt="img" />
<ul class="sb_menu">            
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink3">Link 3</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$('a.newslink1').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", "1.png");
});
$('a.newslink2').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", "2.png");
});
$('a.newslink3').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", "3.png");
});
```

Comment: Will they always be as sequential, incrementing numbers or is it possible that a number may be missing. What part of the `<li>` can be used to get an ID if this is the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a data attribute called data-src:

```
<a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" data-src="1.png">Link 1</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a.newslink").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $("img#storyimg").attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
});
```

Works with jQuery 1.5+.

Answer (score 4):

Change your HTML markup and put the desired image in a data attribute, and change your class to a generic `newslink`:

```
<img id="storyimg" src="1.png" alt="img" />
<ul class="sb_menu">            
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" data-img="1.png">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" data-img="2.png">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" data-img="3.png">Link 3</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

Then do a generic event using that data attribute:

```
$('a.newslink').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", $(this).data('img'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `data-img` attribute to your links:

```
<a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink1" data-img="1.png">
```

which you can then access in the event handler using:

```
$(this).data('img');
```

e.g.:

```
$('.sb_menu a').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('#storyimg').attr(src, $(this).data('img'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/tac3t/

JS:

```
$('a.newslink').live('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", $(this).attr('ref'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<img id="storyimg" src="1.png" alt="img" />
<ul class="sb_menu">            
    <li><a href="#" class="newslink" ref="1.jpg">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="newslink" ref="2.jpg">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="newslink" ref="3.jpg">Link 3</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without changing the markup at all:

```
$('a[class^="newslink"]').bind('mouseover', function (e) {
    var num = this.className.match(/newslink(\d+)/i)[1];
    $('img#storyimg').attr('src', num + '.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could give this a try:

```
$('a.newslink').bind('mouseover', function(){
              var imgname = $(this).attr("src");
              $('img#storyimg').attr("src", imgname);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="storyimg" src="1.png" alt="img" />
<ul class="sb_menu">            
    <li><a href="#" class="newslink" title="1.jpg">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="newslink" title="2.jpg">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="newslink" title="3.jpg">Link 3</a></li>                        
</ul>

$('a.newslink').hover(function(){
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img id="storyimg" src="1.png" alt="img" />
<ul class="sb_menu">            
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" rel='1.png'>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" rel='2.png'>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink" rel='3.png'>Link 3</a></li>                        
</ul>

$('a.newslink').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src", $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Comment: this is not what the `rel` attribute is for.